# Сохранение картинки в файл

Tags: delphi

Как сохранить Bitmap в файл .bmp?

У меня пишет ошибку при вызове `TBitmap.SaveToFile`:

> `Project raised exception class EAccessViolation with message ...`

[image: Ошибка!]

P.S. Не обращайте внимания, что окна цветные, просто я эксперементировал с системной палитрой, а восстанавливать не захотел!

Comment: А метод SaveToFile не сохраняет разве?

Comment: По идее должен, но у меня пишет ошибку, и не сохраняет. Не знаю что компилятору надо?!

Comment: @DelphiM0ZG  Вот что у меня пишет!

Comment: Пробовал ещё имя файла писать просто    'desktop.bmp'
Ещё пробовал без FileCreate('desktop.bmp');

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Может тогда не стоит создавать файл функцией FileCreate(), или же сохранить его в каталог с программой. У меня как-то раз была похожая проблема, но не при сохранении, а копировании файла: в каталоге с прогой - всё нормально, а в другое место копировался, но был пустым.

Comment: Я уже убрал FileCreate, но файл всё равно пустой! А когда сохраняю в каталог с программой, пишет Файл занят другим процессом!!!

Comment: Мои глаза!

Answer (score 3):

Только что по-быстрому набрал этот код - у меня всё прекрасно пашет.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
Var
  Bm: TBitmap;
begin
  Bm:=TBitmap.Create();
  Bm.Width:=400;
  Bm.Height:=300;
  Bm.Canvas.Brush.Color:=clRed;
  Bm.Canvas.FillRect(Rect(0, 0, 400, 300));
  Bm.SaveToFile('bm.bmp');
  Bm.Free;
end;
```

Вы освободили память под Bitmap (Bm.Free;), ещё до того, как сохранили. Посмотрите внимательней.

Comment: Ой, блин, точно!!! Большое спасибо, щас попробую!

Comment: Как вариант, могу ещё предложить программно создать Image и сохранить Bitmap в Image. А из Image, я думаю, точно сохраниться.

Comment: А как из Image сохранить, а то у меня изображение и должно из Image сохранятся, но не нашёл нужного метода, и поэтому использовал Bitmap!

Comment: Всё получилось!!!! Больщое спасибо!!!! Осталось только узнать как можно управлять окнами, если я знаю имя этого процесса!!!

Comment: Так сохранять:
Image.Picture.SaveToFile(SavePictureDialog.FileName+'.bmp');
После чего всё получилось?

Comment: После того, как вспомнил как сохранять!

Answer (score 0):

```
var b,bb: TBitmap;
begin
  b:=TBitmap.Create;
  bb:=TBitmap.Create;
  try
    b.Width:=175;
    b.Height:=175;
    b.PixelFormat:=pf24bit;
    bb.Assign(MenuBackground.Picture.Graphic);
    StretchBlt(b.Canvas.Handle,0,0,175,175,bb.Canvas.Handle,0,0,175,175,SrcCopy);
    b.SaveToFile('save.bmp');
  finally
    b.Free;
    bb.Free;
```

end;
end;